# Accessing Class from Xamarin PCL in Android works but not in iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am a newbie to Xamarin and struggling with C# as well at the moment.
Developing a cross platform Xamarin app (for Android iOS), I have a PCL created with REST services for simple GET method for now.
The goal is to retrieve lastName of a customer based on a query parameter **loginName**

**PCL Code:**

```
public async Task<CustomerResponse> GetCustomerAsync(string inLoginName)
        {
            var url = new StringBuilder().Append(urlProtocol)
                .Append("://").Append(urlDomain)
                .Append("/").Append(urlBase)
                .Append("/").Append(pathParamVersion)
                .Append("/").Append(pathParamLanguage)
                .Append("/").Append(urlGetCustomer);

            url.Append("?").Append(queryParamClientKey).Append("=").Append(queryParamClientVal)
                .Append("&").Append(queryParamChannelKey).Append("=").Append(queryParamChannelVal)
                .Append("&").Append(queryParamLoginNameKey).Append("=").Append(inLoginName);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);

            CustomerResponse customerResponse = null;

            var client = new HttpClient();

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url.ToString());


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                customerResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CustomerResponse>();
            }

            else {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in response");
            }

            return customerResponse;
        }
```

**Android Code in MainActivity.cs for a button Click:**

```
button.Click += async delegate {
                button.Enabled = false;

                CustomerResponse customerResponse = await RESTWSManager.getInstance().GetCustomerAsync("steven");

                button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks! {1}", count++, customerResponse.customer.lastName);

                button.Enabled = true;
            };
```

**iOS Native code (in ViewController.cs)**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            Button.AccessibilityIdentifier = "myButton";
            Button.TouchUpInside += async delegate {

                CustomerResponse customerResponse = await RESTWSManager.getInstance().GetCustomerAsync("steven");

                var title = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++, customerResponse.customer.lastName);
                Button.SetTitle (title, UIControlState.Normal);
            };
        }
```

**Problem**

The problem is with the iOS app whereas in Android it works perfect. I am unable to figure out where the problem is.

In ViewController.cs, **CustomerResponse** shows "type or namespace could not be found" even though it's a public Class. (In android I don't see an error).

Could anyone please help me with a direction to solve this?

Comment: is "CustomerResponse.cs" located in the Android project or in PCL project?

Comment: If `CustomerResponse` is in the PCL, make sure that the PCL is added as a reference to the iOS project.

Comment: Also, are you actually getting a build error if you build? If you are using Xamarin Studio, there are plenty of times where the class names show up red for me like they are not found, but it builds and runs fine. This could be your problem.

Comment: Replace that URL building with string.Format();

Comment: Check your references in the iOS app project.  Since you didn't provide the source for CustomerResponse maybe that uses a class in a library that you DID reference in the android project but not in the iOS project?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I verified References, PCL but there was no luck. I restarted Visual Studio and it started working!!